# Is it possible to migrate Route53 hosted zones from one account to another aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have one public hosted zone in account A with NS and SOA, I want to migrate the hosted zone to account B with the same NS and SOA record because-

1. I want to close the account A and
2. I want to keep the same NS and SOA server.

Answer (score 1):

You can Follow this Simple Guide from [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html) to achieve this also in order to dump created record sets as it you can use utility like [cli53](https://github.com/barnybug/cli53) and use something like

`cli53 export --full domain.com`

**Also remove the `SOA and NS` records of the zone file since it is absolutely crucial that we don’t override the SOA and NS records of the new zone.**

Now to answer the seccond question Unfortunately I do not think it is possible to retain SAME NS Records in new account.
(Note: I Personally have not tried this )

Hope it helps

Comment: You would definitely not be able to retain the same NS records across accounts, so you'd have to change them with the registrar.  But, this also means a conversion does not require downtime -- create the new zone and populate it, then update the registrar.  If the registrar is also Route 53, that also has to be addressed separately.